# jQuery is not loading when I add Intranet site to Intranet Security Zone IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an MVC application and when I added the intranet site (http://192.168.72.196 in the image below) to the Local Intranet sites in Internet Options I get jQuery errors. When I remove the site it works. This only happens in IE.

Is there anyway to fix?

[image]

[image]

I changed the Document setting and it seems to work but I'm not sure what it does or why it's default is 7.

Changed from 7 to Edge
[image]

Comment: where is jquery.js hosted? self-hosted or a CDN? (something like http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js)

Comment: Yes they are please see my edit

Comment: Is the following text in your HTML? `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"> `

Comment: I believe I do @JasonSperske I'm assuming this would cause it to default to 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are caught in the effects of 2 issues.  First your page includes some information that is telling IE to use the IE7 mode, one likely possibility is the inclusion of a meta take like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

Another (harder to track down) possibility is that your web server (ASP.net, PHP etc.) is sending the `X-UA-Compatible` header with the value `IE=7`, [here is more information about this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The other issue is that JQuery 2.0 dropped support for IE 6, 7 and 8, which you can see on their download page:

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Your options are to update the meta tag or header with the value `IE=Edge` or if IE7 support is needed for some other reason, to use JQuery 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

There is a check box in Internet Settings that has bitten me before and it sounds like it is your problem. Press Alt, go to Tools -> Compatibility View Settings. There is a check box that reads "Display Intranet sites in compatibility view." My guess is that is the culprit, especially since the problem only occurs if you put it in the intranet zone. Also note this check box CANNOT be overwritten. Putting a `meta` tag or even a header will not override this check box. If you put an HTTP header, it will override the "document mode" but not the "browser mode." A `meta` tag has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser does not support [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Use polyfill to improve browser compatibility. For example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/2415137#file-addeventlistener-js).

> A polyfill, or polyfiller, is a piece of code (or plugin) that provides the technology that you, the developer, expect the browser to provide natively. Flattening the API landscape if you will.

Source: [What is a Polyfill](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill).

Comment: IE11 has addEventListener. This is not the problem.